# Burninate the "pc" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

- [pc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) — 37 tagged, 15 this year

  > *no tag wiki/excerpt*

As far as I see, it serves no purpose and seems to be randomly tagged on [a wide variety of questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pc) that already seem suitably tagged without the need for the "pc" tag.

Should it be burninated?

Answer (score 3):

I'm all in favor of killing it (and adding a requirement that new tags can only be created by people with >15k rep), but my main concern about killing off tags is the bump to the top of the queue of all the edited posts. I'm utterly convinced that we're better off without that tag, though.

Comment: If we manually edit a post to remove a tag, it gets a bump.  If the tag is removed, or renamed, does the resultant bump actually happen?  I'm not sure.

Comment: I agree with killing it but the rep requirement for new tags is much too high even if there should be one - should be around a few hundred if any. We just need to review new tags more quickly there aren't many

Comment: @Mark The current requirement is [300 rep for new tags](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). IMO this is fine since there are so many new tags that it goes past the 10k tools list.

Comment: @grgarside I agree that rep level that seems reasonable

Comment: Is there any progress on this? I would retag manually but the questions seem appropriately tagged otherwise —cc @stuffe

Comment: We need an answer on bumping.  If binning a tag doesn't bump, then I say bin it.  If it does, then it's worth ignoring on the basis it's just untidy, but not a real problem.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside as far as I know, no, we can't do that.